# How to properly "close" a postgresql php connection

Tags: php, postgresql, postgis

I'm using php and postgresql+postgis to automatically remove nested shells from simplified geojson files, I'm also doing a similar query with pgadmin to get other errors and manually fix them. All is working as needed but the php script won't start correctly sometimes, after starting it just stays there (with no cpu usage on postgresql or php) and I have to restart the postgresql server so the php script can work again.

This is the sql I'm using on both pgadmin and php (query.txt):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION read_file_utf8(path CHARACTER VARYING)
  RETURNS TEXT AS $$
DECLARE
  var_file_oid OID;
  var_record   RECORD;
  var_result   BYTEA := '';
BEGIN
  SELECT lo_import(path)
  INTO var_file_oid;
  FOR var_record IN (SELECT data
                     FROM pg_largeobject
                     WHERE loid = var_file_oid
                     ORDER BY pageno) LOOP
    var_result = var_result || var_record.data;
  END LOOP;
  PERFORM lo_unlink(var_file_oid);
  RETURN convert_from(var_result, 'utf8');
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
SELECT replace(
  ST_IsValidReason(ST_GeomFromGeoJSON(
    read_file_utf8('some_file.geojson')
  )),
  ' ',
  ','
);
```

On php I'm running pg_query like this:

```
$query = file_get_contents('query.txt');
$dbc = pg_pconnect('host=localhost port=5432 dbname=XXX user=XXX password=XXX');
if (!pg_connection_busy($dbc)) {
  $has_error = true;
  while ($has_error) {
    $res = pg_query($dbc, $query);
    if ($row = pg_fetch_row($res)) {
      if (!fix_json($row[0])) { $has_error = false; }
    }
    else { $has_error = false; }
  }
}
pg_close();
```

When I restart the postgresql service I get this error on php:

```
Warning: pg_query(): Query failed: FATAL:  terminating connection due to administrator command
CONTEXT:  while updating tuple (180,4) in relation "pg_proc"
server closed the connection unexpectedly
```

I'm on windows 10 x64 1703, php x64 5.6.30, postgresql server x64 10.1